# How to upload InputStream via HttpPut from Apache HttpClient 4.x

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-put

I'm trying to upload an `InputStream` via `HttpPut` using the Apache HttpClient 4.5.6:

```java
InputStream inputStream = ..
CredentialsProvider provider = ..
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
                .build();

HttpPut method = new HttpPut("MY_REMOTE_URL");
InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(inputStream);
method.setEntity(entity);
client.execute(method);
```

Uploading requires authentication and in my case I don't know if the Server used digest or basic authentication, therefore the client automatically sends multiple requests to determine the authentication scheme. But `InputStreamEntity` is non repeatable , leading to the following errors:

```
org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity.
```

---

### Idea #1: Buffering the InputStream

I can wrap the entity with `BufferedHttpEntity` which makes it repeatable:

```java
..
BufferedHttpEntity entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(new InputStreamEntity(inputStream));
method.setEntity(entity);
..
```

.. but then the stream first gets buffered and then sent in total, not chunked / streamed. This does not work for bigger files.

---

### Idea #2: Preemptive Authentication

I can add a hardcoded header with the correct authentication to prevent the request from being repeated. But as I said, I don't know the authentication scheme.

---

### Idea #3: Dummy FileEntity upload to get context (my current solution)

I upload an empty file first, harvest the context and add it to my InputStream PUT request:

```java
HttpPut testMethod = new HttpPut("MY_REMOTE_DUMMY_URL");
FileEntity testEntity = new FileEntity(testFile);
testMethod.setEntity(testEntity);
HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
client.execute(testMethod, context);

// .. delete the testEntity from server ..

HttpPut method = new HttpPut("MY_REMOTE_URL");
InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(inputStream);
method.setEntity(entity);
client.execute(method, context);
```

It works, but it seems like a hack. Should I do this? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate `expect-continue` handshake instead.

```java
HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setExpectContinueEnabled(true).build();
context.setRequestConfig(config);
```

Comment: It did answer my question! Will try to edit the answer providing the relevant code snippet.